How do I extract a specific output from Jinja?
Slightly new to this but essentially, I want to extract the specific value from an output. The following code
 {{ result("execute_dql_query_1")["records"] }}
produces the following output
 [{'value': 1, 'boolean': 'File exists', 'interval': '120000000000'}]
Essentially, what I want to return is whatever is contained within the 'value' or the 'boolean' category.
I used CoPilot which suggested selectattr() but I have not been able to get it to work and get an error. I am using Dynatrace which may limit my ability to do this but would like to see what options are out there.

Could you know just  update your query to only return the value?  Or are you saying you don't have access to that due to just having dynatrace ?  Also, update your question with the code you have tried so someone can assist.

In this specific case: {{ result("execute_dql_query_1")["records"].0.boolean }} and {{ result("execute_dql_query_1")["records"].0.value }}. But mind that [] denotes an array, so, if you do have more than one record returned, your best bet is probably to have a for loop: something like {% for record in result("execute_dql_query_1")["records"] %}{{ record.value }}{% endfor %}

The best is that you describe your desired output more throughtly, so we can provide an answer to this.
